# Is it possible to get thirty OWLs?

Tags: harry-potter

In 'The Chamber of Secrets' novel, Ron says that Tom Riddle might have gotten the *Award for Special Services* for a variety of odd reasons

> ‘Could’ve been anything,’ said Ron. ‘**Maybe he got thirty O.W.Ls** or
>   saved a teacher from the giant squid. Maybe he murdered Myrtle, that
>   would’ve done everyone a favour …

But **is this actually possible?** Has JKR given any history on this?

Comment: There are only [12 OWL subjects](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ordinary_Wizarding_Level) mentioned in the text. Ron was clearly using hyperbole.

Comment: @Richard Ah, of course. The trio does that.

Comment: I seem to recall the theory and practical sections were given separate tests, which are averaged for the OWL grade for the subject.  It may be, then, the number got doubled conversationally to emphasize his proficiency... All O's might mean one each theory and practical for 12 subjects, and the leap from "24 O's" to "30 OWLs" is a lot more manageable for an exaggeration... and might be something honestly misheard with just three more classes.

Comment: O and OWL is different. To secure an OWL, you need the pass grade, i.e A,  E or O. O is the highest grade of the three.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be a case of Ron using [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole). We know from elsewhere in the texts that there are only [12 OWLS taught at Hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/how-did-bill-and-percy-get-12-owls?rq=1). While it's theoretically possible that there were more subjects in the past (or that there are [vastly more OWLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education#Subjects) than those that are normally taught), the reality is that he was almost certainly exaggerating for effect.

For the record, we also know that the giant squid is actually [quite pleasant](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts_Giant_Squid) and doesn't really need anyone saving from it.

Comment: Very misunderstood fella the giant squid.

Answer (score 6):

Ron is being his usual self here, a.k.a. exaggerating. The [*twelve* possible O.W.Ls](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ordinary_Wizarding_Level) are:

- Charms
- Transfiguration
- Herbology
- DADA
- Ancient Runes (though only Hermione does this out of the trio)
- Potions
- Care of Magical Creatures
- Astronomy
- Divination
- Arithmancy
- History of Magic
- Muggle Studies

Riddle could have gained, at max, 12 - not thirty. It's also entirely possible that Ron was trying to be sarcastically scathing and not *entirely* getting it - another very Ron-like practice.

Comment: This also means that anyone getting 12 OWLs was using Time-Turners too, as Hermione was in her third year.

Comment: @cst1992 - Not necessarily. As I pointed out in another answer, Hermione needs a time-turner because her lessons conflict with each other. It may be that other students who got 12 OWLS just had a schedule that didn't conflict that year.